# Problema con la autenticación en Laravel 8 (Error 401 después de loguear)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy trabajando con la autenticación sin paquetes de Laravel 8 además de esto estoy usando dos tablas (Multi Auth) con diferentes nombres de atributos (es decir, password no se llama así sino "contrasena"); la creación de sesión y la autenticación se crean perfectamente pero hay un fallo en AuthenticationException donde dice que la ruta de destino tras hacer el login no esta autenticada y eso es en lo que no entiendo.

Contextualicemos, tengo el controlador Login donde se encarga de ambos logins (tanto de administrador como de vigilante ~son dos usuarios diferentes y los requerimientos pedían dos tablas diferentes y no una sola tabla de usuarios, que era lo más evidente y más fácil), apartando esto tengo los controladores tanto de administrador como de vigilante donde se encargan de hacer el CRUD y otras funcionalidades, así que no sé si hay que pasar un dato o algo que identifique que el administrador esta autenticado.

Suministro mi código para que se den a la idea:

web.php (Logout aparentemente funciona)

```
Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('users.auth');
Route::get('admin', [LoginController::class, 'master'])->name('administrador')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('admin/logout', [AdministradorController::class, 'logout'])->name('admin.logout');
```

Formulario de login.blade.php

```
<form id="login-master" action="{{ route('users.auth') }}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
           <div class="mx-5 px-5">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col">
                          <div class="form-group my-3">
                               <label>Usuario</label>
                               <input class="form-control" id="user" name="username" type="number">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group my-3">
                               <label>Contraseña</label>
                               <input class="form-control" id="pass" name="password" type="password">
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                     <a href="#" class="px-3">Olvidaste tú contraseña</a>
                     <button type="submit" id="confirmar-ingresar" class="btn btn-success">Ingresar</button>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

(Estoy utilizando modales de Bootstrap, mi proyecto no se basa tanto en vistas)

script.js (Envió el formulario por AJAX para modificar el modal en tiempo real y no recarga de página)

```
    $('#login-master').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var login = $(this);
        var data = login.serializeArray();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: login.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function($data) {
                $('.alert-danger').html('');
                if($data.success == false) {
                    $('.alert-danger').show();
                    $('.alert-danger').append($data.error);
                }
                else if($data.errors) {
                    $('.alert-danger').show();
                    $('.alert-danger').append('<ul>');
                    $.each($data.errors, function(key, value){
                        $('.alert-danger').append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                    });
                    $('.alert-danger').append('</ul>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.alert-danger').hide();
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

AdministradorController.php (Solo dejaré la función master por ser la vista que se va a cargar cuando se haga login)

```
public function master()
{
    return view('administrador.administradorindex');
}
```

LoginController.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username'   => 'required|min:7',
            'password' => 'required|min:5'
        ]);
        
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json( ['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()] );
        }

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['documento' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], true)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $request->session()->put('role', 'admin');
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo());
        }
        if(Auth::guard('vigi')->attempt(['documento' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('vigi');
        }
        return response()->json( ['success' => false, 'error' => 'Verifique los datos de ingreso']);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'documento';
    }

    protected function redirectTo() {
        $user = "";
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        }
        switch ($user->role) {
            case 'admin':
                return route('administrador');
                break;

            default:
            return route('login');
            break;
        }
    }
```

Administrador.php (En este ejemplo solo vamos a utilizar este modelo)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Administrador extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $table = 'administradors';
    protected $primaryKey = 'documento';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'documento' => 'integer'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'contrasena'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'documento',
        'nombres',
        'cargo',
        'contrasena'
    ];

    public function encrypt($contrasena)
    {
        return Hash::make($contrasena);;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->contrasena;
    }

    public function getRoleAttribute()
    {
        return 'admin';
    }
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $user = "";
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            $user = Auth::guard($guard)->user(); 
        }

        if($user != "") {
            switch ($user->role) {
                case 'admin':
                    return redirect()->route('administrador');
                    break;
                
                default:
                    return redirect()->route('login');
                    break;
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Authenticate.php

```
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        $user = "";
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        }
        //$user = $request->session()->get('role');
        if($user != "") {
            switch ($user->role) {
                case 'admin':
                    return route('administrador');
                    break;
                
                default:
                    return route('login');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Y por último auth.php

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'administradors' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Administrador::class,
    ],
    'vigilantes' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Vigilante::class,
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'administradors'
        ],
        'vigi' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vigilantes'
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
        'administradors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Administrador::class,
        ],
        'vigilantes' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Vigilante::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'administradors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Administrador::class,
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'vigilantes' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Vigilante::class,
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Todo esto es basado en muchos post y vídeo tutoriales que he venido viendo durante una semana y aún así nada que me solucione este problema... el error sucede cuando pasa por el middleware de "auth", aquí hay algo que genera el AuthenticateException y da como error el código 401 (Unauthenticated.) aunque a veces me aparece "Unauthorized" y no sé porque pasa, se supone que ya debe estar bien pero no avanza, no autentica; además quito el middleware de la ruta de administrador y si carga la vista pero no verifica evidentemente si esta logueado o no, carga a pesar de colocar el enlace directo en el navegador.